# How do I use ObjectID from a mongoimport?

Tags: meteor

I use a mongoimport to import a bunch of large csv files into a meteor collection, however when they do the insertions the _id values are ObjectID, whereas meteor uses string ids. There's a small blurb on ObjectIDs in the meteor docs [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#collection_object_id) but I don't really understand what I am supposed to do. For example, using Iron Router I have a single route like so

```
this.route('profileView', {
        path: '/profiles/:_id',
        notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
        fastRender: true,
        waitOn: function() {
            return [Meteor.subscribe('singleProfile', this.params._id, Meteor.userId())];
        },
        data: function() {
            Session.set('currentProfileId', this.params._id);
            return Profiles.findOne({
                _id: this.params._id
            }, {
                fields: {
                    submitted: 0
                }
            });
        }
```

but the url of the route is of type object and looks like `http://localhost:3000/profiles/ObjectID(%22530845da3621faf06fcb0802%22)`. It also doesn't return anything and the page renders blank. Here's the publication.

```
Meteor.publish('singleProfile', function(id, userId) {
    return Profiles.find({
        _id: id,
        userId: userId,
        forDel: {
            $ne: true
        }
    });
});
```

I guess my question is, how am I supposed to use ObjectIDs so that the routes use just the string portion of the ObjectID, and how do I return the data properly?

Update: I've managed to get the ObjectID out of the url by changing the link to the view from `<a href="{{pathFor 'profileView'}}" class="profile-details">Details</a>` to `<a href="/profiles/{{_id._str}}" class="profile-details">Details</a>` so the url is now `http://localhost:3000/profiles/530845da3621faf06fcb0802`. Unfortunately, the page still renders blank, and I am not sure if that's because of the way I am subscribing, publishing, or finding the collection item.

Comment: What happens if you replace all instances of `this.params._id` with `new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(this.params._id)`?

Comment: @Cuberto I get an error `Exception from Deps recompute: Error: Invalid hexadecimal string for creating an ObjectID`

Comment: @landland you'll have to only use the stuff in the brackets, i.e for `ObjectID(%22530845da3621faf06fcb0802%22)` you need `530845da3621faf06fcb0802` as `this.params.id`

Comment: @Akshat. No luck. When I print to console, this.params._id is 530845da3621faf06fcb0802 but the page still renders blank. The publish and route code are otherwise unchanged.

Comment: the string part of the objectid can be obtained by simply calling `._str` on the id. Also, take a look at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1834 and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/f-ljBdZOwPk for pointers

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy I did that in my update, used ._str in the template. This allowed me to get this.params._id as the string part. Unfortunately the page still renders blank.

Comment: about your update: you can now find by `_id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(this.params._id)` since your URL param is now a string and you can craft the objectid from that string

Comment: success! thank you so much. If you write an answer I can mark it as accepted. Does this mean that everytime I do a find, update, or remove and I have the string part, I'll need to do a do something like Profiles.remove({_id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(id)})?

Comment: Yes but only if the `id` is coming as a string from a route or any other function. If on the other hand, it is a proper objectid that you got from another referencing document, than you use it as it is. You can use a pattern like `IDAsString = this._id._str ? this._id._str : this._id` or `IDAsObjectId = this._id._str ? this._id :  new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(this._id)` I feel like I just contributed partially so I don't want to hijack the answer :) @Cuberto and @Akshat had already pointed towards the right direction so I think it should be one of them :)

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification. yes, it was definitely a team effort and I am very grateful. Whoever wants to write up an answer I'll go ahead and accept.

Comment: rats, one more thing. If I navigate to the page, everything is good, but if I go to the url directly or refresh, page is blank. any ideas? the findOne returns undefined.

Comment: Hm, I think your problem is very similar to https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/380 where Meteor.user() is not ready when you access the page directly, so you need to actually wait for the users subscription as well

Answer (score 2):

Summing up the comment thread as an answer:

The string part of the ObjectID can be obtained by simply calling ._str on the id as

```
id._str
```

You can also craft an ObjectID from a hex string by using

```
new Meteor.Colletion.ObjectID(hexstring)
```

So when you access your route using `<a href="/profiles/{{_id._str}}" class="profile-details">Details</a>` you can craft your find like:

```
Profiles.findOne({
  _id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(this.params._id)
});
```

Generally speaking, when working with ObjectID's, you will find yourself needing some antipatterns to convert from string to objectId or vice versa, so a utility like the following will come in handy:

```
IDAsString = this._id._str ? this._id._str : this._id
```

and

```
IDAsObjectId = this._id._str ? this._id :  new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(this._id)
```

*Please also take a look at github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1834 and groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/f-ljBdZOwPk for pointers and issues around using ObjectID's.*